# How do I print int into array variable of char type in C?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Input maze:

```
##..##############
##..............##
########..########
##........##....##
##..########..####
```

Output expected:

```
##00##############
##++02++04++06++##
########++########
##++08++06##----##
##10########--####
```

here I have stored maze as 2d array into structure as:

```
struct mazecells{
    char symbol;
    int reachable;
    int visited;
    int clear;
    int costs;
};

typedef struct maze {
    struct mazecells M[BUFFERSIZE][BUFFERSIZE];
    int startx, starty;
    int numrows, numcolumns;
    int initdir;
}maze_t
```

so whenever my program traverse through `maze path` i.e. `'.'`, I have assigned cost to that path using `maze->M[pos.y][pos.x].costs = <cost_value>`.
Now while printing output as shown above, I need to print the cost value instead of maze symbol. I have written below code but it is printing some random junk characters. How can I achieve it.

```
    if (maze->M[i][j].costs !=0)
    {
        printf("%c",  '0');
        printf("%c",  maze->M[i][j].costs);
    }
```

it's giving below output:

```
##++##############
##0☺0☻0♥0♦0♣0♠0##
########0♣########
##0     00♠##....##
##++########..####
```

Comment: `printf("%c",  '0'); printf("%c",  maze->M[i][j].costs);` --> `printf("%02d",  maze->M[i][j].costs % 100);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY - Thanks a lot. it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to translate the number in "cost"  to string, you must use one of:
        1. Use %d instead of %c. 
        2. Use the ascii table and convert your number to char. 
        3. Use %s with itoa funtion. 
Actually you were printing ascii code of the number (cost)  but not the number